# CSS bg-img cover the "first look/visit"

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, background-image

I'm working on a website and I want to cover the whole "first look", "first visit" with a background-image. The next content should only be visible when you scroll down.  For example : https://www.piccola-koeln.de/ 
Like their first background-image, the photo of their restaurant.

I hope I could describe what I need help with.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/yj0rqccL/

```
<div class="bg"></div>

.bg {
  height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  background:url(https://i.imgur.com/sduLRvf.jpg);
}
```

This unit will match the viewport height. Make sure you do a min-height so when the height of browser is made smaller, you elements will stay in place.